# Automatically creating a vendor using GravityForms and WooCommerce Product Vendors

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My site is running WordPress with the following plugins:

- WooCommerce
- WooCommerce Product Vendors (http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-vendors/)
- GravityForms
- Gravity Forms User Registration Add-On
- Gravity Forms PayPal Standard Add-On

What I need to have happen is whenever someone signs up through a specific GravityForm (there are two – one which doesn’t require payment and one that does), a user is created and that person is given “vendor” status where they can post and manage their own products. Creating the user is simple with the GravityForms User Registration addon, but falls apart with the Product Vendor stuff because the plugin expects each vendor to be created manually… The vendors plugin doesn’t use roles or capabilities in the traditional manner, so it’s been tricky to come up with a solution.

With some research, I found the following snippet of code that claims it can create a new product vendor on user creation:

```
**
* Create a vendor on account registration.
*
* @param int $customer_id
* @param array $new_customer_data
* @return boid
*/
function wc_create_vendor_on_registration( $customer_id, $new_customer_data ) {
$username = $new_customer_data['user_login'];
$email = $new_customer_data['user_email'];
// Ensure vendor name is unique
if ( term_exists( $username, 'shop_vendor' ) ) {
$append = 1;
$o_username = $username;
while ( term_exists( $username, 'shop_vendor' ) ) {
$username = $o_username . $append;
$append ++;
}
}
// Create the new vendor
$return = wp_insert_term(
$username,
'shop_vendor',
array(
'description' => sprintf( __( 'The vendor %s', 'localization-domain' ), $username ),
'slug' => sanitize_title( $username )
)
);
if ( is_wp_error( $return ) ) {
wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Unable to create the vendor account for this user. Please contact the administrator to register your account.', 'localization-domain' ), 'error' );
} else {
// Update vendor data
$vendor_data['paypal_email'] = $email; // The email used for the account will be used for the payments
$vendor_data['commission'] = '50'; // The commission is 50% for each order
$vendor_data['admins'][] = $customer_id; // The registered account is also the admin of the vendor
update_option( 'shop_vendor_' . $return['term_id'], $vendor_data );
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'wc_create_vendor_on_registration', 10, 2 );
```

This works on its own, but I don't want it to fire every time a user registers, only when my GravityForm is completed.

What I need to do is combine that with GravityForm’s gform_after_submission hook and alter it so that it pulls values from the submitted form:
http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/gravity-forms/extending-gravity-forms/hooks/actions/gform_after_submission/

Here's what I came up with, but it's not working and I'm not sure why:

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_2", "wc_create_vendor_on_registration", 10, 2);
function wc_create_vendor_on_registration( $customer_id, $new_customer_data ) {
    $username = $entry["12"];
    $email    = $entry["8.1"]; 

    // Ensure vendor name is unique
    if ( term_exists( $username, 'shop_vendor' ) ) {
        $append     = 1;
        $o_username = $username;

        while ( term_exists( $username, 'shop_vendor' ) ) {
            $username = $o_username . $append;
            $append ++;
        }
    }

    // Create the new vendor
    $return = wp_insert_term(
        $username,
        'shop_vendor',
        array(
            'description' => sprintf( __( 'The vendor %s', 'localization-domain' ), $username ),
            'slug'        => sanitize_title( $username )
        )
    );

    if ( is_wp_error( $return ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Unable to create the vendor account for this user. Please contact the administrator to register your account.', 'localization-domain' ), 'error' );
    } else {
        // Update vendor data
        $vendor_data['paypal_email'] = $entry["9.1"];  // The email used for the account will be used for the payments
        $vendor_data['commission']   = '50'; // The commission is 50% for each order
        $vendor_data['admins'][]     = $customer_id; // The registered account is also the admin of the vendor

        update_option( 'shop_vendor_' . $return['term_id'], $vendor_data );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'wc_create_vendor_on_registration', 10, 2 );
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code directly in your question?

Comment: Sure! Will update shortly

Comment: Without actually testing this, I can see that '$username = $entry["12"];` will be blank right away as there is no `$entry` variable defined anywhere. I would suggest turning on `WP_DEBUG` mode and also perhaps killing your custom function in places with `die($text_variable)` just to see the status of certain variable at certain points.

Comment: My GF is pretty out of date since I don't use it, but I did manage to find ` do_action('gform_user_registered', $user_id, $config, $entry, $user_pass);` in the user registration add-on. Assuming it is still there, you should try to fire your create vendor function on that hook and adjust your variables to those passed in via that hook.

Comment: Any known solution for this?